# DavMail + Office365

Tags: office365, outlook.com

Does anyone know what Exchange OWA URL I should use for connecting to Office 365 via DavMail? Tried:

```
https://portal.microsoftonline.com/
https://pod51013.outlook.com/ews/exchange.asmx
https://pod51013.outlook.com/owa/
```

Many thanks

Comment: Note that at least currently you can probably connect to office 365 over IMAP

Answer (score 24):

https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx is working for me after a frustrating few hours.

DavMail 4.7.2-2427, with "Exchange protocol" set to EWS.

A "/owa/" URL was in place up until I was forced to change my domain password yesterday.  (We've got our domain server up in Azure and integrated with our 365 AD and get redirected to our own ADFS for authentication.... or something.)

Using the /owa/ url I was getting a "554 Authenticated failed All network interfaces down or host unreachable !" error out of DavMail which seemed to have been the result of the underlying Apache HTTP classes not liking the web-page it was getting back.  ("Unrecognized cookie attribute: name=HttpOnly, value=null")

Comment: Thanks for this. For my information, how did you guess this URL?

Comment: @oliv Googling + the recollection of maybe having used it (the /EWS/Exchange.asmx bit) for an on-premise Exchange in the past.

Comment: I can concur that this works with a recent (up-to-date as of September 2016) version of DavMail and an Office365 account provided by my academic institution. Immediately prior, as this answer notes, just the `/owa/` URL was working fine, and before _that_, the `podXXXXX.outlook.com` host was what I had been using successfully for several years. Neither of those other options seem to function anymore, and the [DavMail ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/davmail/support-requests/236/) mentioned below has some context on that.

Comment: This worked for me, though I also had to change my thunderbird username from `DOMAIN\username` to `DOMAIN\username@company.com`. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately using https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx does not work for me - no matter how I play around with the username.
My company has a two factor auth in place that requires verification via a mobile phone code. I assume that is the reason. Is there any way to deal with that in conjunction with Davmail?

Comment: @Chris If I understand correctly, you can create an app password [here](https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/AppPasswords.aspx) (when you're logged in to Office 365) for applications that cannot handle two-factor authentication.  Write it down immediately, because you won't be able to see it again, and use that password instead of the one you got from your employer.

Answer (score 14):

Go to mail.office365.com and you should be redirected to a [host].outlook.com/owa/ address. Use that as your OWA URL in DavMail and also be sure that "Enable EWS" is selected in the Advanced tab of DavMail settings. Use your full OWA domain as your username to log in (i.e. **user@domain.com**) and you should be in there like a dirty shirt.

Answer (score 10):

I got this from https://sourceforge.net/p/davmail/support-requests/236/.

```
davmail.url=https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx

davmail.enableEws=true
```

then update Thunderbird/OUTLOOK to have yourusername@yourcompany, for both incoming and smtp and you should be good.

Comment: This appears to have fixed it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

After testing several other possibilities, the value which was for working for me in property "OWA (Exchange) URL" was :

```
https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?realm=mycompany.com
```

Edit : This URL does not work anymore for me since 29/04/2016 (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in cookie handling).  Maybe it still works for some setups ?

Comment: I have also started to face same issues for the last one week. I see StringIndx**Exception and my calendar is not syncing. I get this error in my log and it stops fetching calendar. davmail.exchange.ExchangeSession  - Connect exception: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException String index out of range: -1

Answer (score 3):

This is now covered [in the DavMail FAQ](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/faq.html#General):

> **Office 365**
>
> Office 365 EWS endpoint is now standard for all customers:
> https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
>
> Also make sure you set mode to EWS in settings
>
> **Is Office 365 modern authentication / MFA supported ?**
>
> Office 365 modern authentication is available with the following
> modes:
>
> - O365Interactive: will open an authentication window to let you enter your credentials and go through MFA check and
> - O365Modern: same logic as O365Interactive, but use client provided credentials for Oauth negotiation, trigger PhoneApp MFA check
>   transparently

Personally I didn't have any joy with *O365Modern*, but *O365Interactive* worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

At http://help.outlook.com/en-us/beta/dd936216.aspx you'll find instructions on how to determine the name of your Office365 server under the question "How do I find the server settings?"

For example, your connection details might look like this:

> Your Name
>
> Help
>
> Use these settings to access your email using POP, IMAP or SMTP.
>
> POP setting
>   Server name: xyz.outlook.com
>   Port: 99999
>   Encryption method: SSL
>
> IMAP setting
>   Server name: xyz.outlook.com
>   Port: 99999
>   Encryption method: SSL
>
> SMTP setting
>   Server name: xyz.outlook.com
>   Port: 99999
>   Encryption method: TLS

Using the name of the server, you can form the name of the Exchange OWA server.

In this case:

```
 https://xyz.outlook.com/owa/
```

There are also hints at http://help.outlook.com/en-au/140/dd125429.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can find your own URL by testing your account in https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com
Then, search in the bunch of information to find it.

Sometimes, your company has its own servers and address and outlook.office365.com is not the way to go !

Answer (score 1):

if you have a working Outlook setup you can **CTRL-Right-Click** on the **Outlook Icon** in the notification part of the task bar (**system tray**) and you will get an option called "***Test E-mail auto configuration***".

If you run that with **your email** address (password is not required) it will take a while and a report is shown. Look for a **line** that **ends on exchanges.asmx** and that is likely to be the **URL you need**.

I setup davmail wiht Office 365 this way and it works.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's something with outlook.com... you can find the url within your administrative console.

Answer (score 0):

Should be just the OWA URL like this:
https://amsprd0302.outlook.com/owa/

Answer (score 0):

If you always get error message like "authentication failed All network interface down davmail", maybe u should login https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx firstly, and it will tell you that:

```
You have created a service.

To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:


svcutil.exe https://ch2pr19mb4024.namprd19.prod.outlook.com:444/EWS/Services.wsdl
This will generate a configuration file and a code file that contains the client class. Add the two files to your client application and use the generated client class to call the Service. For example:

C#

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        HelloClient client = new HelloClient();

        // Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.

        // Always close the client.
        client.Close();
    }
}

Visual Basic

Class Test
    Shared Sub Main()
        Dim client As HelloClient = New HelloClient()
        ' Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.

        ' Always close the client.
        client.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then you can send mail with smtp without problems!